# Editable Data Table for Assigning Helpers to Drivers

Tags: vue.js

I am just learning Vuejs and I am implementing it in a 'legacy' environment where jQuery, Bootstrap 3, among other libraries are loaded by default. In my implementation I try to keep it simple with certain functionality built in. My codepen is stripped of a few things such as some fetch calls and related things, so static data is loaded in. I recognize that some libraries conflict, such as Bootstrap 3 styling of select lists styling with Vuetify select component styling, so I am trying to figure out how to use the 'A-la-carte' functionality of Vuetify, to only import the Data Table component, so any input on that would be appreciated.

Functionality built-in:

- A helper can only be assigned to one driver at a time, so the list of available helpers changes dynamically
- Changes are only temporarily saved until the 'save' button is clicked

I would like for my code to be as clean, elegant, and efficient as possible so any feedback for achieving that would be appreciated. Additionally, I would like to follow best practices.

Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/betapup/pen/oNgOmPz

```js
$(function() {
    /**
     * Load and initialize the Module Object
     */
  
    var getUrl = window.location;
    var baseUrl =
      getUrl.protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split("/")[1];
    console.log(baseUrl);
  
    var dataLoadApp = new Vue({
      el: "#DispatchList",
      vuetify: new Vuetify(),
      data: function() {
        return {
          search: "",
          singleSelect: false,
          selected: [],
          loading: false,
          headers: [
            { text: "Dispatch No", value: "DPA_SYS_NR", class: "col-xs-1" },
            { text: "Route No.", value: "RTE_LST_SYS_NR", class: "col-xs-1" },
            { text: "Route Name", value: "RTE_NA", class: "col-xs-1" },
            { text: "Operation Date", value: "dpa_opr_dt", class: "col-xs-1" },
            { text: "Driver", value: "driver", class: "col-xs-2" },
            { text: "Helper", value: "helper", class: "col-xs-2" },
            { text: "Start Time", value: "HPR_STT_TM" },
            { text: "Meeting Location", value: "meetingloc", class: "col-xs-2" },
            { text: "Edit", value: "edit", class: "col-xs-2" }
          ],
          dispatchList: [
            {
              RTE_NA: "32D",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "LAKE FOREST",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "MISSIOJ VIEJO ",
              HPR_FST_NA: "THOMAS",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234996",
              RTE_LST_SYS_NR: "37021433",
              MTG_AD_TE: "27000 CROWN VALLEY ",
              DPA_SYS_NR: "23652016",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "949-422-8235",
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92691     ",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057596757396015",
              MTG_NA: "MISISON VIEJO MALL - 27000 CROWN VALLEY ",
              DPA_OPR_DT: "December, 02 2019 00:00:00",
              DVR_FST_NA: "EDGAR",
              MTG_TE: "MISISON VIEJO MALL",
              DVR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057599595327456",
              DVR_LST_NA: "Viper                       ",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "92630",
              HPR_LST_NA: "Tiger",
              HPR_STT_TM: "10.5",
              isEditable: false,
              updating: false,
              unsavedEdit: { HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: 0, MTG_SYS_NR: 0 }
            },
            {
              RTE_NA: "22B",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "LAGUNA NIGUEL",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "ALISO VIEJO",
              HPR_FST_NA: "FRANK",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234948",
              RTE_LST_SYS_NR: "37021042",
              MTG_AD_TE: "22 BROOKLINE",
              DPA_SYS_NR: "23652017",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "949-212-1104",
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92656     ",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057607295908652",
              MTG_NA: "33D McD - 22 BROOKLINE",
              DPA_OPR_DT: "December, 02 2019 00:00:00",
              DVR_FST_NA: "MARK",
              MTG_TE: "33D McD",
              DVR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057596755776331",
              DVR_LST_NA: "Cat                          ",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "92677",
              HPR_LST_NA: "Gecko",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11",
              isEditable: false,
              updating: false,
              unsavedEdit: { HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: 0, MTG_SYS_NR: 0 }
            },
            {
              RTE_NA: "85C",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "SAN CLEMENTE",
              HPR_FST_NA: "CARLOS",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234956",
              RTE_LST_SYS_NR: "37021043",
              MTG_AD_TE: "638 CAMINO DE LOS MARES",
              DPA_SYS_NR: "23652018",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "858-263-6437",
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92672",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057607569786758",
              MTG_NA: "76B McD STORE LOS MARES - 638 CAMINO DE LOS MARES",
              DPA_OPR_DT: "December, 02 2019 00:00:00",
              DVR_FST_NA: "DANNY",
              MTG_TE: "76B McD STORE LOS MARES",
              DVR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057596757396156",
              DVR_LST_NA: "Leopard                         ",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "     ",
              HPR_LST_NA: "Mouse",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11",
              isEditable: false,
              updating: false,
              unsavedEdit: { HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: 0, MTG_SYS_NR: 0 }
            },
            {
              RTE_NA: "58C",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "MISSION VIEJO            ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "LAGUNA NIGUEL",
              HPR_FST_NA: "CHRISTIAN",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234973",
              RTE_LST_SYS_NR: "37021045",
              MTG_AD_TE: "30120 TOWN CENTER",
              DPA_SYS_NR: "23652019",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "0000000000",
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92677     ",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057604790204638",
              MTG_NA: "82A BALLPARK PIZZA - 30120 TOWN CENTER",
              DPA_OPR_DT: "December, 02 2019 00:00:00",
              DVR_FST_NA: "FRANCISCO",
              MTG_TE: "82A BALLPARK PIZZA",
              DVR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057596757442558",
              DVR_LST_NA: "Hippo                  ",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "92691",
              HPR_LST_NA: "Aligator",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11.5",
              isEditable: false,
              updating: false,
              unsavedEdit: { HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: 0, MTG_SYS_NR: 0 }
            },
            {
              RTE_NA: "21E",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "",
              HPR_FST_NA: "",
              MTG_ST_CD: "",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "0",
              RTE_LST_SYS_NR: "37021047",
              MTG_AD_TE: "",
              DPA_SYS_NR: "23652021",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "",
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "0",
              MTG_NA: " NONE",
              DPA_OPR_DT: "December, 02 2019 00:00:00",
              DVR_FST_NA: "AARON",
              MTG_TE: "",
              DVR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057599394692259",
              DVR_LST_NA: "Sheep                        ",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "",
              HPR_LST_NA: " NONE",
              HPR_STT_TM: "0",
              isEditable: false,
              updating: false,
              unsavedEdit: { HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: 0, MTG_SYS_NR: 0 }
            }
          ],
          helpers: [
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "0",
              HPR_FST_NA: "",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "",
              HPR_LST_NA: " NONE",
              HPR_STT_TM: "0",
              assigned: true
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "949-940-6656",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "Mission Viejo",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057596755718987",
              HPR_FST_NA: "MICHAEL",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "     ",
              HPR_LST_NA: "Caribou",
              HPR_STT_TM: "10.5",
              assigned: true
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "949-422-8235",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "LAKE FOREST",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057596757396015",
              HPR_FST_NA: "THOMAS",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: 92630,
              HPR_LST_NA: "Tiger",
              HPR_STT_TM: "10.5",
              assigned: true
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "949-903-6797",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057599664221092",
              HPR_FST_NA: "CARLOS",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "     ",
              HPR_LST_NA: "Raccoon",
              HPR_STT_TM: "10.5",
              assigned: false
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "714-381-8800",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "MISSION VIEJO",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057601806790785",
              HPR_FST_NA: "LOUIE",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: 92691,
              HPR_LST_NA: "Lemur",
              HPR_STT_TM: "10.5",
              assigned: false
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "0000000000",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "MISSION VIEJO            ",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057604790204638",
              HPR_FST_NA: "CHRISTIAN",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: 92691,
              HPR_LST_NA: "Aligator",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11.5",
              assigned: true
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "7142926373",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "HUNTINGTON BEACH         ",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057604998433690",
              HPR_FST_NA: "KYLE",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: 92647,
              HPR_LST_NA: "Dog",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11",
              assigned: false
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "949-456-3705",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "MISSION VIEJO            ",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057606938145111",
              HPR_FST_NA: "AARON",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: 92691,
              HPR_LST_NA: "Kangaroo",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11",
              assigned: false
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "949-212-1104",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "LAGUNA NIGUEL            ",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057607295908652",
              HPR_FST_NA: "FRANK",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: 92677,
              HPR_LST_NA: "Gecko",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11",
              assigned: false
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "9495994286",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "MISSION VIEJO            ",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057607368946249",
              HPR_FST_NA: "RYAN",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: 92692,
              HPR_LST_NA: "Jackal",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11.5",
              assigned: false
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "858-263-6437",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057607569786758",
              HPR_FST_NA: "CARLOS",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "     ",
              HPR_LST_NA: "Mouse",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11",
              assigned: true
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "949-374-9030",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057609580449451",
              HPR_FST_NA: "JUDE",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "     ",
              HPR_LST_NA: "Badger",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11",
              assigned: true
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "949-942-9190",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057609582686402",
              HPR_FST_NA: "DANTE",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "     ",
              HPR_LST_NA: "Toucan",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11",
              assigned: false
            },
            {
              EMP_ID_NR: "",
              CEL_PHN_NR_TE: "530-718-0175",
              HPR_CTY_TE: "LAGUNA NIGUEL",
              HPR_EMP_SYS_NR: "72057609648129924",
              HPR_FST_NA: "MICAH",
              HPR_ZIP_TE: "     ",
              HPR_LST_NA: "Sea Otter",
              HPR_STT_TM: "11",
              assigned: true
            }
          ],
          meetingLocs: [
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "",
              MTG_NA: " NONE",
              MTG_TE: "",
              MTG_ST_CD: "",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "0",
              MTG_AD_TE: ""
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92691     ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "MISSIOJ VIEJO ",
              MTG_NA: "MISISON VIEJO MALL - 27000 CROWN VALLEY ",
              MTG_TE: "MISISON VIEJO MALL",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234940",
              MTG_AD_TE: "27000 CROWN VALLEY "
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92692     ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "MISSION VIEJO",
              MTG_NA: "CANYON CREST ESToucanS - 22300 CANYON CREST DRIVE",
              MTG_TE: "CANYON CREST ESToucanS",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234942",
              MTG_AD_TE: "22300 CANYON CREST DRIVE"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92656     ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "ALISO VIEJO",
              MTG_NA: "33D McD - 22 BROOKLINE",
              MTG_TE: "33D McD",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234948",
              MTG_AD_TE: "22 BROOKLINE"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92672     ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "SAN CLEMENTE",
              MTG_NA: "76B McD STORE LOS MARES - 638 CAMINO DE LOS MARES",
              MTG_TE: "76B McD STORE LOS MARES",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234956",
              MTG_AD_TE: "638 CAMINO DE LOS MARES"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92677     ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "LAGUNA NIGUEL",
              MTG_NA: "80C McD STORE (MARINA HILLS) - 30251 GOLDEN LANTERN",
              MTG_TE: "80C McD STORE (MARINA HILLS)",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234957",
              MTG_AD_TE: "30251 GOLDEN LANTERN"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92679     ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "LADERA RANCH",
              MTG_NA: "21B WAGON WHEEL SPORTS PARK - SPORTS PARK",
              MTG_TE: "21B WAGON WHEEL SPORTS PARK",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234963",
              MTG_AD_TE: "SPORTS PARK"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92692     ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "LADERA RANCH",
              MTG_NA: "21F BURGER KING - 27702 CROWN VALLEY PARKWAY",
              MTG_TE: "21F BURGER KING",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234967",
              MTG_AD_TE: "27702 CROWN VALLEY PARKWAY"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92677     ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "LAGUNA NIGUEL",
              MTG_NA: "82A BALLPARK PIZZA - 30120 TOWN CENTER",
              MTG_TE: "82A BALLPARK PIZZA",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234973",
              MTG_AD_TE: "30120 TOWN CENTER"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92677     ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "LAGUNA NIGUEL",
              MTG_NA: "82C ALBERTSONS LAG NIGUEL - 29941 ALICIA PARKWAY",
              MTG_TE: "82C ALBERTSONS LAG NIGUEL",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234976",
              MTG_AD_TE: "29941 ALICIA PARKWAY"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "DANA POINT",
              MTG_NA: "25D ALBERTSONS - 33601 DEL OBISPO/STONEHILL",
              MTG_TE: "25D ALBERTSONS",
              MTG_ST_CD: "  ",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234984",
              MTG_AD_TE: "33601 DEL OBISPO/STONEHILL"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92692     ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "MISSION VIEJO",
              MTG_NA: "CASA DEL SOL POD - CASTA DEL SOL",
              MTG_TE: "CASA DEL SOL POD",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "234996",
              MTG_AD_TE: "CASTA DEL SOL"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92694     ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "MSSION VIEJO",
              MTG_NA: "21D -McD STORE ANTONIO - 27762 ANTONIO PKWY",
              MTG_TE: "21D -McD STORE ANTONIO",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "235010",
              MTG_AD_TE: "27762 ANTONIO PKWY"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "  ",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "LADERA RANCH",
              MTG_NA: "21C SHELL - OSO/ANTONIO",
              MTG_TE: "21C SHELL",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "235013",
              MTG_AD_TE: "OSO/ANTONIO"
            },
            {
              MTG_ZIP_CD: "92637",
              MTG_CTY_NA: "LAGUNA WOODS",
              MTG_NA:
                "ARAGON - 24232 CALLE ARAGON, LAGUNA WOODS LAGUNA WOODS, CA 92637",
              MTG_TE: "ARAGON",
              MTG_ST_CD: "CA",
              MTG_SYS_NR: "240897",
              MTG_AD_TE: "24232 CALLE ARAGON, LAGUNA WOODS LAGUNA WOODS, CA 92637"
            }
          ],
          tempEdit: []
        };
      },
      created: function() {},
      methods: {
        shortDate(longDate) {
          var d = new Date(longDate);
          return d.toLocaleDateString("en-US");
        },
        helperIsAssigned(helperSysNr) {
          return this.dispatchList.some(
            dispatchObj => dispatchObj.HPR_EMP_SYS_NR == helperSysNr
          );
        },
        makeEditable(dispatchObj) {
          let dispatchItem = this.dispatchList[
            this.dispatchList.indexOf(dispatchObj)
          ];
          dispatchItem.unsavedEdit["HPR_EMP_SYS_NR"] =
            dispatchItem["HPR_EMP_SYS_NR"];
          dispatchItem.unsavedEdit["MTG_SYS_NR"] = dispatchItem["MTG_SYS_NR"];
          dispatchItem["isEditable"] = true;
        },
        cancelEditable(dispatchObj) {
          let dispatchItem = this.dispatchList[
            this.dispatchList.indexOf(dispatchObj)
          ];
          dispatchItem["isEditable"] = false;
          dispatchItem.unsavedEdit["HPR_EMP_SYS_NR"] = 0;
          dispatchItem.unsavedEdit["MTG_SYS_NR"] = 0;
        },
        saveDispatchItem(dispatchObj) {
          let dispatchItem = this.dispatchList[
            this.dispatchList.indexOf(dispatchObj)
          ];
          dispatchItem["updating"] = true;
          dispatchItem["isEditable"] = false;
          dispatchItem["HPR_EMP_SYS_NR"] =
            dispatchItem.unsavedEdit["HPR_EMP_SYS_NR"];
          dispatchItem["MTG_SYS_NR"] = dispatchItem.unsavedEdit["MTG_SYS_NR"];
          let helperEmpSysNr = dispatchItem["HPR_EMP_SYS_NR"];
          var helperObj = this.helpers.find(
            ({ HPR_EMP_SYS_NR }) => HPR_EMP_SYS_NR === helperEmpSysNr
          );
          dispatchItem = Object.assign(dispatchItem, helperObj);
  
          let meetingSysNr = dispatchItem["MTG_SYS_NR"];
          var meetingLocObj = this.meetingLocs.find(
            ({ MTG_SYS_NR }) => MTG_SYS_NR === meetingSysNr
          );
          dispatchItem = Object.assign(dispatchItem, meetingLocObj);
        },
        setHelper(e, dispatchIndex) {
          let dispatchObj = this.dispatchList[dispatchIndex];
          const helperObj = this.helpers.find(
            helper => helper.HPR_EMP_SYS_NR == e.target.value
          );
          helperObj["assigned"] = true;
          let currHelper = this.helpers.find(
            helper => helper.HPR_EMP_SYS_NR == dispatchObj["HPR_EMP_SYS_NR"]
          );
          currHelper["assigned"] = false;
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/2.1.7/vuetify.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>CodePen - Vuetify Data Table Template Test</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
    <div id="DispatchList">
      <v-app>
        <v-container>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              Assign Helper List
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-data-table
              v-model="selected"
              :headers="headers"
              :items="dispatchList"
              item-key="DPA_SYS_NR"
              :loading="loading"
              loading-text="Loading... Please wait"
            >
              <template v-slot:item.DPA_OPR_DT="{ item }">
                <span>
                  {{ shortDate(item["DPA_OPR_DT"]) }}
                </span>
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.driver="{ item }">
                <span>
                  {{ item["DVR_FST_NA"] + " " + item["DVR_LST_NA"] }}
                </span>
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.helper="{ item }">
                <span v-if="item['isEditable'] === false">
                  {{ item["HPR_FST_NA"] + " " + item["HPR_LST_NA"] }}
                </span>
                <select
                  v-else
                  @change="setHelper($event, dispatchList.indexOf(item))"
                  class="form-control"
                  v-model="item.unsavedEdit['HPR_EMP_SYS_NR']"
                >
                  <option
                    v-for="helper in helpers"
                    v-show="item['HPR_EMP_SYS_NR'] == helper['HPR_EMP_SYS_NR'] ? !helper['assigned'] : !helper['assigned']"
                    :value="helper['HPR_EMP_SYS_NR']"
                  >
                    {{ helper["HPR_FST_NA"] + " " + helper["HPR_LST_NA"] }}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.meetingloc="{ item }">
                <span v-if="item['isEditable'] === false">
                  {{ item["MTG_NA"] }}
                </span>
                <select
                  v-else
                  class="form-control" v-model="item.unsavedEdit['MTG_SYS_NR']">
                  <option
                    v-for="meetLoc in meetingLocs"
                    :value="meetLoc['MTG_SYS_NR']"
                  >
                    {{ meetLoc['MTG_NA'] }}
                  </option>
                </select>
              </template>

              <template v-slot:item.edit="{ item }">
                <button
                  v-if="item['isEditable'] === false"
                  class="btn btn-default"
                  title="Edit Dispatch Item"
                  @click="makeEditable(item)"
                >
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                </button>
                <span v-else>
                  <button
                    class="btn btn-danger"
                    title="Cancel Edit"
                    @click="cancelEditable(item)"
                  >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
                  </button>
                  <button
                    class="btn btn-primary"
                    title="Save Dispatch Item"
                    @click="saveDispatchItem(item)"
                  >
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
                  </button>
                </span>
              </template>
            </v-data-table>
          </v-card>
        </v-container>
      </v-app>
    </div>
    <!-- partial -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```